# IE: unable to get Favicon for static page

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, favicon

So, I have a unique requirement of sending the offline website ( static HTML CSS, js, and static assets) to the user.

I am facing the issue that when the user opens their HTML file in Internet Explorer, Edge and safari they are not able to see the FavIcon on the page.

I searched on Stackoverflow and referred a couple of answers but none seem to work. Some answers that I referred suggested :

1) keep favicon.ico on the root of the application. 
2) check the favicon ( generated thrice and verified that it works when I host this on a web server) 
3) Add different flavors of rel and href when importing favicon. like: x-code, icon, short icon, etc.

Is this something related to security and can not be bypassed if we are serving static HTML?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you see load of favicon in console network tab?

Comment: I downloaded some webpages and tested and found that if we open the local static page, the favicon didn't show in IE&Edge Legacy but showed in Chrome and Edge Chromium. I think that's by design in different browsers, due to some different security reasons and we can't change it.

Comment: This makes sense. I finally gave that up and communicated to the client. @YuZhou

Comment: Yes, the favicon can show through server but can't show through local offline page.